# Exit vim insert mode in Mozilla Firefox Style Editor

Tags: firefox, vim, mozilla, firefox-developer-tools

Inside of the style editor for Mozilla Firefox web dev, I have my Keybindings set to 'Vim' (preferred). The problem is inside of the Style Editor I cannot exit insert mode; I usually would press escape to do this in any Vim editor, however in Mozilla this is bound to the shortcut of 'open console'. How can I either exit insert mode or change the key bindings in Firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to switch to normal mode and <kbd>i</kbd> to go to insert mode.

I'm not sure how to change the keybindings but here are some things to get you started.

The Editor component is a thin wrapper around the [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) open source editor.

[vim bindings demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html)
[vim api in the manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#vimapi)

Comment: Thank you, there are a lot of resources on the site. As they state there: "Note that while the vim mode tries to emulate the most useful features of vim as faithfully as possible, it does not strive to become a complete vim implementation".

Comment: @Joe, glad I could help, BTW did you look at this file?
http://codemirror.net/keymap/vim.js
It's near the 50th line or so that I found the mapping
Still doesn't explain why <esc> doesn't work.